# Change the background of rotated image to White instead of black after using Projection Profile Deskew method in OpenCV (or skimage)

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, opencv, python

I have used `Projection Profile` method on my binary images to get the deskew version. Everything is fine but the rotated image is having Black areas where the deskewing has been applied. **How can I convert that area to white instead of black**. Below is the code for Projection Profile.

```
def correct_skew(image, delta=1, limit=5):  
    """
     image : input
     delta : sampling in the -limit,limit + delta range
     limit : range of angles to explore 

    """
    # Function that returns the score of histogram for the given angle at which we check
    def determine_score(arr, angle):
        """
         arr   : binarized image
         angle : angle at which we calcuate the score
        """
        data = inter.rotate(arr, angle, reshape=False, order=0)
        histogram = np.sum(data, axis=1)
        score = np.sum((histogram[1:] - histogram[:-1]) ** 2)
        return histogram, score

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] 

    scores = []
    angles = np.arange(-limit, limit + delta, delta)
    for angle in angles:
        histogram, score = determine_score(thresh, angle)
        scores.append(score)

    best_angle = angles[scores.index(max(scores))]

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, best_angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    return best_angle, rotated
```

This is the Image after Deskewing:

[image: Image After Deskewing]

Original Binary Image:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cv2.warpaffine documentation states that the function takes an optional argument namely `borderValue`. By default this value is `(0, 0, 0)`, You can change this by calling your warpaffine routine as:

```
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=np.array([255, 255, 255]))
```

Comment: Thanks bud! Worked smoothly.